# Tikz won't plot the function properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I tried to plot the following function but it didn't work:

`y = 300 + 1000/x + 2.5x`.

This is the document, but instead of the plot it only shows the axis.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}% This uses tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Function}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{300 + 1000/x + 2.5}%
}

\tikzset{My Line Style/.style={smooth, thick, samples=400}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0.0,
    xmax=250,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=50,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left, 
    xlabel= $y$,
    ylabel=Cost, 
    xtick={250},
    xticklabels={250},    
    restrict x to domain=0:250,
    ]   
    \addplot+[My Line Style, color=black, samples at={1,2,3,4,...,249,250}] (\x,{Function(\x)});


\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\documentclass{article}
```

Comment: You're limiting the y axis to the range from 0 to 50, but the minimum value of your function in your domain (x=0 .. 250) is 300. Remove the `ymax=50` and you'll see the function. By the way, the function in your question and code are different (`+2.5` vs. `+2.5x`)

Comment: Note also that you can use `samples at={1,...,250}` to get the same result that you get with `samples at={1,2,3,4,...,249,250}`

Comment: @Mark, would you care to write a self-answer on this one? Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Answering per information in the comments.

I set `compat=1.9` instead of `compat=newest` so this solution will work even if a future update breaks compatibility.

I also updated the declaration of your function to match what is written in the question text. In your style `My Line Style`, `samples=400` is redundant since you're using `samples at=<...>` below.

The problem was `ymax=50`, which clipped the plot with none of the function showing. I have commented this out to automatically set the limit, but you could also change it to a more appropriate value.

I also adjusted the contents of `samples at=<...>` to produce (in my opinion) better mark spacing. You could also use Jake's suggestion of `samples at={1,...,250}`, or, equivalently, `samples=250, domain=0:250`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}% This uses tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% use current version at time of writing

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Function}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{300 + 1000/x + 2.5*x}% corrected to written form in question text
}

\tikzset{My Line Style/.style={smooth, thick}} % samples=400 is redundant since you specify samples at below

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0.0,
  xmax=250,
  ymin=0,
  %ymax=50, % <<< this was the problem
  axis x line=bottom,
  axis y line=left, 
  xlabel= $y$,
  ylabel=Cost, 
  xtick={250},
  xticklabels={250},    
  restrict x to domain=0:250,
]   
    \addplot+[My Line Style, color=black, samples at={1,2,3,4,6,9,16,...,250}] (\x,{Function(\x)});
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]